# Can i install component and plugin with single extension in joomla package?

Tags: joomla3.0

I want to know if we can install plugin and component with a single extension? for example i created a plugin to send the trackback, and i create a component to import articles and i want to include them in a single package . Is it possible?Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is it related to programming? If it is, add what you have tried, especially code. If it is more joomla- than programming-related, ask on joomla.stackexchange.com instead. My gut says the latter is true, but I'm not sure.

Comment: i got it to work.. sorry i overlooked joomla.stackexchange. also made sure  that i i gave the url for reference as answer. sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible... Try http://joomla-extensions-packager.org, there is a form for generating extension packages online by uploading extensions / filling a form. If you need some automation, you can use the php library to generate your packages programatically (by php cli scripts, phing etc.)

Comment: Essential part of the answer is "Yes, it is possible" ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry My bad. There is this thing called package in joomla where  you can pack module and plugin  or vice-versa.

You can find the detailed explaination here.Sorry for the quick question

[Joomla Packages](https://docs.joomla.org/Package)